# A question about the Bessel function $I_0$

Tags: definite-integrals, bessel-functions, change-of-variable

I'm studying from notes taken in class, the context of which is not relevant to the question. The problem is simply as follows. I have this expression:

$$f(y)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{\phi=0}^{2\pi}e^{y\cdot\cos(\phi-\phi_0)}\,\mathrm{d}\phi$$

and in the notes I read that immediately:

$$f(y)=I_0(y)$$

This is not so clear to me, because I know that the definition of the $0$-th order modified Bessel function is:

$$I_0(y)=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{t=0}^{\pi}e^{y\cdot\cos(t)}\,\mathrm{d}t$$

and I can't find a simple change of variable that transforms $f(y)$ into $I_0(y)$.

Comment: Look at the unit circle. Cos is the x coordinate which starts going back after $\pi$ radians. That is why you will get double contribution if you take the whole roundtrip.